# Small subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, trace

Suppose $d>1$ is a natural number. I am trying to compute traces of products of $2^d \times 2^d$ matrices of the form Tr($A_{i,d}A_{j,d}\cdots A_{k,d}$) where $A_{i,d}$ are of the form:
$$
A_{0,3}=\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\  
1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\  
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\  
0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\  
0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\  
0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\  
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\  
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\  
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad A_{1,3}=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
A_{2,3} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
A_{3,3} = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm not sure how to proceed to compute the traces (looks difficult I think). However I thought that perhaps it's smart to look for decompositions 
$$A_{i,d} = \sum_m e_m E_m$$ So my question:

Does there exist subgroups of GL$(2^d)$ such that elements $\{E_j\}$ are orthonormal with respect to the inner product $\langle E_j,E_i \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(E_jE_i)$ for all $i,j,d$?